# Proper way to query objects with Inverse relationships in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm currently having trouble querying data that I stored in an Inverse relationship. I have the following code

```
class Form: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    ...
    var answers = List<FormAnswer>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
...
}
```

and

```
class FormAnswer: Object {
    dynamic var key = ""
    dynamic var answer = ""
    let form = LinkingObjects(fromType: Form.self, property: "answers")

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }
}
```

When I create a FormAnswer object I do the following:

```
 try! realm.write {
            let answer = FormAnswer(value: ["key": key, "answer": answer, "form" : parentForm!]) // parentForm is of type "form"
            realm.add(answer, update: true)
}
```

And when I try to query it, I get nothing!

```
let previousValue = realm.objects(FormAnswer.self).filter("key == %@ AND ANY form.id == %@", key, parentForm!.id).first?.answer
```

I've checked the realm file with Realm Browser, and there's an entry for FormAnswer. But there are only 2 fields (key and answer) and there doesn't appear to be a link to my Form object.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkingObjects` is a computed property and cannot be mutated directly. Instead you modify its values by changing the other side of the relationship.

Try:

```
try! realm.write {
    parentForm.answers.add(FormAnswer(value: ["key": key, "answer": answer]))
}
```

This adds the new answer directly to the `Form`'s `answer` list, and will result in the answer's `form` property containing `parentForm`.